# Run a GWT page without backing server?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, canvas

As GWT translates java-code to JavaScript: is it afterwards possible to run a page without a backingserver? Like just production the html,css,js folder and just running it in a browser without a server?

Especially when using GWT with Canvas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely, yes. If you don't have a need for a server then, well, you don't need a server.

Note: you'll have to use the `xsiframe` linker if you intend to serve the files from disk rather than HTTP. In most browsers the `std` linker (the default linker) won't work with `file://` URLs.

Comment: Where do you configure xsiframe vs. std linker?

Comment: `<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>` in your `*.gwt.xml`. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModuleXml